# Change then unchange the colour of an object when clicking it in excel

Tags: excel, vba

**Problem:**
I am struggling to change the colour of a bunch of graphic tick marks I have in excel when clicking them.

**Solution:**
I am looking to change them to Green if clicked (individually, Not all together) and then changed back to grey if clicked again.

This should be an easy code but very limited with my VBA experience as I am just getting started and got really stuck with this. Please help!

**Here's what it looks like:**
[image]

Comment: Hi there. Sorry, I had tried researching a lot and tried a few attempts. For next time, I will be sure to include my efforts here. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick Event, you can achieve your expected results, the code below will illustrate how to change the cell color from Grey to Green and back if double clicked once more:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then 'check if double click happens in Column A
    Cancel = True 'Stop the cursor accessing the cell
        If Target.Font.ColorIndex = 16 Then 'check if the cell colour is grey, amend to reflect your actual ColorIndex
            Target.Font.ColorIndex = 50 'change cell color to green
        ElseIf Target.Font.ColorIndex = 50 Then 'if cell is green
            Target.Font.ColorIndex = 16 'change to grey
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Xabier but that did not quite work because it was not the cells that were coloured instead the tick mark graphics that were in the cell. But no worries, with some variation I was able to make it work in a similar functionality as shown below. Thank you!

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A21:A500")) Is Nothing Then
    Cancel = True
        If Target.Interior.Color = vbGreen Then 
            Target.Interior.Color = vbRed
        ElseIf Target.Interior.Color = vbRed Or Target.Interior.Color = vbWhite Then
            Target.Interior.Color = vbGreen
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Comment: Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeRightClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Me.Range("A21:A500")) Is Nothing Then
    Cancel = True
        Target.Interior.Color = vbWhite
    End If
End Sub